# Update Knockout Observable string in refresh function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, typescript

The code is in typescript and I am trying to show current date time on page load and update that date time on refresh click.

In .ts file string that shows date time is declared like this.

```
   asOfString: KnockoutObservable<string>;
```

In the constructor it is being set like this,

```
 this.asOfString = ko.observable(new Date().toDateString() + " " + new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
```

In html it is being bind like this,

```
           <a class="small button" data-bind="click: updateSummary">Refresh</a>
```

In refresh button I am trying to update it like this,

```
 this.asOfString(new Date().toDateString() + " " + new Date().toLocaleTimeString()); //latest date time.
```

It gives me an error that _this.asOfString is not a function.

Please help.

Code of the view model is like this,

```
import ko = require('knockout');

class TodayViewModel {
    asOfString: KnockoutObservable<string>;

    constructor() {
        this.updateSummary();

        this.asOfString = ko.observable(new Date().toDateString() + " " + new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
    }

    updateSummary = () => { // is the function that is bound to refresh button
        //want to update this.asOfString here
    }
}

export = TodayViewModel;
```

Comment: We need to see more of your code for when you're updating it (to get an idea of what the value of `this` is). Post how you define your view model, how `asOfString` is defined on your view model, and how `updateSummary` is defined on your view model. Additionally, ensure that `asOfString` is not being overwritten anywhere with something that isn't an observable.

Comment: Sounds like a wrong `this`. The `updateSummary` function used in the click binding will (by default) **not** be called with your view model as `this`

Comment: let me know if html is required. but it is just a span tag bound to asOfString  and a refresh button bound to updateSummary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine for me as the entire app. I can't tell what I'm doing differently from what you describe, so I'm just including the whole thing.

```
class TodayVM {
    asOfString: KnockoutObservable<string>;

    constructor() {
        this.asOfString = ko.observable('');
        this.updateSummary();
    }
    updateSummary = () => {
        this.asOfString(new Date().toDateString() + " " + new Date().toLocaleTimeString())
    }
}

window.onload = () => {
    ko.applyBindings(new TodayVM());
};
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>TypeScript HTML App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>TypeScript HTML App</h1>

    <div data-bind="text:asOfString"></div>
    <button data-bind="click:updateSummary">Update</button>
</body>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: The main difference is that in OPs code `this.updateSummary();` was called before assigning to `this.asOfString`.